# How can i write a query that returns all objects except a given one?

Tags: typo3-flow

im trying to write a simple query that would be easy if i had access to the persistence_object_identifier. I kickstarted my models and so i dont have them.

What i want to do is:

```
function getAllExcept($obj){
  $query = $this->createQuery();
  $query->matching(
     $query->logicalNot(
         $query->equals('persistence_object_identifier', $obj)
     )             
    );
  return $query->execute();
}
```

I tried a lot but i cannot make it work.
I could easily call ->toArray() and filter the one object out, but the fluid pagination widget needs the QueryResultInterface...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property's name is `Persistence_Object_Identifier` (mind the case). It is injected by AOP in https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.Flow.git/blob/HEAD:/Classes/TYPO3/Flow/Persistence/Aspect/PersistenceMagicAspect.php#l58.

Comment: Thank u so much. That case switch solved it totally.

Answer (score 0):

replace

$query->equals('persistence_object_identifier', $obj);

with

$query->equals('Persistence_Object_Identifier', $obj);

It will work.